# Optimal flash settings for macro photography (Nikon SB-900 + softbox)

Tags: nikon, flash, macro, softbox

I'm using a [Nikon SB-900](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Flashes/4807/SB-900-AF-Speedlight.html) along with a [softbox](https://www.google.se/search?q=flash%20softbox&sugexp=chrome,mod=14&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=XyrsULDVEo-L4gSf94GYCA&biw=1920&bih=971&sei=ZSrsUNCZE6nL4ASlk4CoAQ) when photographing macro (1:1).

What I would like to know is what flash mode that would fit this setup best. Should i simply set it to "M" and adjust it on each picture depending on the results, or should i use TTL? Or perhaps none of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should i simply set it to "M" and adjust it on each picture depending
>   on the results, or should i use TTL?

There's not a single correct answer here other than *do what works for you*. If TTL gives you results that you like, great! That's what it's there for, right? Otherwise, manual mode is fine -- adjust parameters like the flash power, flash zoom, and distance to get the lighting you want. The point of manual mode is to let you set the flash the way you want when TTL isn't cutting it.